# How to use the component string returned from server in React via AJAX

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, I am trying to render a component from the string return by Server side ReactDomServer.renderToString(), could anyone give me a working patrn or example to do this in AJAX?

A case will be:

One the init page, there is a dropdown, you choose different type of componnet, then it will submit AJAX request to server, then server return according string, then the page will render that component on it.

Thanks

Comment: If you're just using `renderToString()`, why would you not instantiate the components on the client side?

Comment: A quick google search for isomorphic react: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-react-isomorphic-javascript-why-it-matters/

Comment: @MikeD Thanks, but I did not quite catch that part: which part in that post is talking about the AJAX pattern to update partial of the component, I need render a component without resend a page( I do not want to use res.render in Express.js handler for component request)

Comment: There's no good way to do what you're wanting. React is *meant* to run in the browser. Why are you offloading rendering to the server?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller cos I want to generate component according to user's initial config params submitted to server then generate component according to those params plus some server side data. And store all those params on server side, so that when user login from somewhere else, I can produce same UI and send to user. Basically sync user UI everywhere and being able to update

Comment: I think there are two separate concerns that are getting mixed: state and UI. The server can compute data and store persistent state and pass that to the client, but it should not be telling the client how to draw the UI. The client app should ask the server for information and pass back changed information, and then use that information to draw a UI however it makes sense.

Comment: OK, so you mean each time, I load all component into browser with initial state data(no matter what updated before) and then ask server for the latest UI state data, right? But I wonder what if I create a component, is that a different pattern as sync existing components?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Say the app is all about building components, just like using old-time visual basic studio to draw a user window and bind event to components on it, how can I achieve that in React? LIke I choose a component and click and drag to draw it on the page

Comment: That's probably too complicated to answer in a comment, but there are still two distinct pieces. Consider the drag-and-drop UI builder example. You have a list of available components that is drawn into a toolbar of some kind. On drag, there is a DOM element that moves, but as far as we are concerned, it is just an object of data that we receive on drop. We would add that configurable object to a component tree object (a "ui spec", if you will) that we would use to draw React components. But we would never *lose* that spec in favor of elements or strings - it tells us what to draw next time.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Thanks. Could you give me a little code example/fiddle about how to implement a simple drag-draw-render workflow  on client side in React? Say I want to add a simple form component to page with one text input and one button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on your question, it sounds like what you're looking to do is dynamically render a UI.

Your request was for an example of a drag-and-drop rendering workflow, but that would stray too far from your question. It's important that we first tease out the many components and then focus on the one that's interesting for this question. We have a data layer and server-side responsible for storing information, business logic for determining how components should render where and when, interaction paradigms like drag and drop that work within these rules, and the rendering of components based on them.

All of these are separate concerns that must be considered independently. For example, drag and drop is *one way* to add components, but it is likely to not be the *only* way, so why couple the two? That leaves us with just rendering dynamic components, which I shall consider here. I'll be using ES2015 syntax to make the code cleaner.

First, we have a main component that does the wrapping:

```js
const Renderer = React.createClass({
  render () {
    // ...
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Renderer layout={layout} />,
  document.getElementById( 'app' )
);
```

Now let's consider the components you mentioned, which will be pure:

```js
const Button = ({ text }) => (
  <button>{text}</button>
);

const Input = ({ type = "text", placeholder }) => (
  <input type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />
);
```

And some container for available components (which would likely also have metadata and rules about each):

```js
const Components = {
  Button,
  Input,
};
```

And now let's assume we have a configuration defined in json:

```json
{
  "name": "My Interface",
  "layout": [
    { "id": 123, "component": "Input", "placeholder": "keywords..." },
    { "id": 456, "component": "Button", "value": "Search!" },
  ],
}
```

This is highly simplified, but you can imagine this document showing all properties for a deeply nested UI, perhaps sporting different types of containers like rows and columns. Now we can assume the JSON property `layout` is the `layout` property passed to the `Renderer` above. Now our `render` function can look like this (highly simplified):

```js
render () {
  const children = this.props.layout.map( ({ component, ...props }) => {
    const Component = Components[ component ];
    return <Component {...props} />
  });

  return (
    <div className="component-view">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Whenever the model changes, we would re-render the component tree and see what we should. There is a *lot* that would have to go into something like this to get a full UI editor - that's a **massive** undertaking. But with proper design principles and separation of concerns, it's at least *doable*.

To return to drag and drop briefly, if we were to drag and drop, we would note its place and insert the component into the tree however made sense based on the component and the state of the item onto which it's dropped, etc. The result of the operation, assuming it was successful, would be a mutated layout tree, which triggers a re-render.

**Note:** I completely ignored performance considerations.